# PHP eats linefeed in php/plaintext mixed mode

Tags: php, text

This one is bothering me for a while. Let's say we have a simple PHP-File:

```
Line 0
Line 1
<?="Line 2"?>
Line 3
```

Processing this file will result in:

```
Line 0
Line 1
Line 2Line 3
```

Where did the line feed after `?>` go? The linefeed is not beeing devoured when placing some character after the closing tag (e.g. `?>.`).

Is there a way to control this behaviour? I'm not willing to place whitespaces after the closing tag, because my IDE is configured to remove whitespaces before linefeeds (and I like it that way).

Comment: Don't use HTML mode to generate text files; that's asking for trouble :)

Comment: Adding an additional linefeed would of course work, but I'd rather like PHP to spare my first one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, indeed:

> The closing tag for the block will include the immediately trailing newline if one is present.
>
> http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php

Meaning, if the `?>` is the last thing on the line, the newline will be removed as part of the closing PHP block. You need to explicitly `echo` a newline or add an additional newline.

Comment: This behaviour does not make sense to me. Why would anyone want this? There should be way to switch it off some day :-/

Comment: @Felix Some code blocks don't produce output, and you don't necessarily want them litter newlines all over the place; say `<?php foreach ($foo as $bar) : ?>`. Yes, what PHP does is not a great solution. ERB for Ruby and others have *whitespace control*, e.g. `-%>` (`-` controls the output or not-output of following newlines/whitespace). PHP should add that.

Comment: Ha, thanks for the Ruby reference, I actually thought something like this was a part of PHP twenty years ago when I learned it but I did encounter Ruby later on.

Answer (score 4):

This [is actually a feature](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php) (believe it or not). PHP consumes a linefeed if it directly follows a PHP close tag:

> The closing tag for the block will include the immediately trailing
>   newline if one is present.

This was clearly put in so that a PHP file ending with a blank line would not cause a newline to occur in the output when `include`d from another script. So it's really a "protect the ignorant" feature from the old days that we have to live with for the foreseeable future.

If you really want the newline there are other options: from simply putting in *two* newlines after the closing tag (the second will work!) to echoing a newline from code.

Answer (score 1):

Outside of the `<?php` and `?>` tags, the PHP interpreter operates in HTML mode and spacing inside HTML mode is less of an issue than it is for text contents.

To generate text with PHP you should use plain strings and build your output in this fashion:

```
$var = "Line 2";
$s = "Line 0\nLine 1\n$var\nLine3";
```

At least this won't give you a nasty, though [documented](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php), surprise :)